# How to display MYSQL query result column_1 is querying this year, column_2 is querying a year ago?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to display a query result like this:

```
|  Who_was_born_this_year | Who_was_born_year_ago |
___________________________________________________
|     x                   |    y                  |    
|     x                   |    y                  |
```

where x will display Name of people who born in this year and y will display Name of people who born a year ago

TABLE PEOPLE STRUCTURE:

```
   ID people | ID Gender | Name   | Birthday
   _________________________________________
   1         | 1         | John   | 18-07-2015
   2         | 1         | Stu    | 12-01-2014
   3         | 2         | Leslie | 10-03-2014
```

All date format is dd-mm-yyyy

How can i achieve this with a query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    IF (YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(Birthday), Name, '') Who_was_born_this_year,
    IF (YEAR(CURDATE())-1 = YEAR(Birthday), Name, '') Who_was_born_year_ago
From people
;
```

but you will receive something like:

```
|  Who_was_born_this_year | Who_was_born_year_ago |
___________________________________________________
|    John                 |                       |
|                         |    Stu                |
|                         |    Leslie             |
```

and i suppose that it's not exactly what you desire...

But it's the best in this situation, because we don't have key how we should bind data for this year and for last year...

Or:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT group_concat(Name)
    FROM people
    WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(Birthday)
) Who_was_born_this_year,
(
    SELECT group_concat(Name)
    FROM people
    WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-1 = YEAR(Birthday)
) Who_was_born_year_ago
;
```

but in this case you will receive something like:

```
|  Who_was_born_this_year | Who_was_born_year_ago |
___________________________________________________
|    John                 |                       |
|                         |    Stu,Leslie         |
```

and i again suppose that it's not exactly what you desire...

I think that it's not the best idea to represent data in way you wish...

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query this query may help you,

```
SELECT
  (CASE YEAR(Birthday) WHEN YEAR(curdate()) THEN name ELSE NULL END) as Who_was_born_this_year,
  (CASE YEAR(Birthday) WHEN YEAR(curdate() - interval 1 year) THEN name ELSE NULL END) as Who_was_born_year_ago 
FROM people WHERE YEAR( Birthday )IN (YEAR(curdate() - interval 1 year),YEAR(curdate()));
```

you can also optimize this query by selecting curent year and previous year firstly